# Cannot convert bitmap to byte[]

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bitmap, xamarin.android

So I'm making a Xamarin.Forms app. I have a StackLayout, of which I'm taking a snapshot(only the element, not the whole screen.)

This is the interface:

```
public interface IViewSnapShot
{
    Task<byte[]> CaptureAsync(Xamarin.Forms.View view);
}
```

this is the event:

```
private async Task SavePic_ClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var imageByte = await DependencyService.Get<IViewSnapShot>().CaptureAsync(BlueprintSnapshot);
    }
```

and this is Android platform specific:

```
public class MakeViewSnapshot : IViewSnapShot
{
    Task<byte[]> IViewSnapShot.CaptureAsync(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
    {
        var nativeView = view.GetRenderer().View;
        var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled;
        nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        nativeView.BuildDrawingCache(false);
        Bitmap bitmap = nativeView.GetDrawingCache(false);
        // TODO: Save bitmap and return filepath
        nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;

        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return bitmapData;
    }
}
```

The problem is `bitmapData` gives error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'byte[]' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

I have search internet, and every post says that this is the way to convert bitmap to byte[] array. Any idea how to fix this error?

Later I'll want to upload the byte[] array to web api.

Comment: You either need to ditch your Task return signature, or wrap the method in a Task

Comment: Why is it marked async but you return a byte[]? That is the problem, you should be returning a task, or remove the async task and just return the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning a `byte[]`, you can use the [Task.FromResult()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.fromresult?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_FromResult__1___0_) to wrap a result into a `Task`:

```
return Task.FromResult(bitmapData);
```

Your code might looks like this:

```
public class MakeViewSnapshot : IViewSnapShot
{
    Task<byte[]> IViewSnapShot.CaptureAsync(Xamarin.Forms.View view)
    {
        var nativeView = view.GetRenderer().View;
        var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled;
        nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        nativeView.BuildDrawingCache(false);
        Bitmap bitmap = nativeView.GetDrawingCache(false);
        // TODO: Save bitmap and return filepath
        nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;

        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

And then later when you want to get the `byte[]` returned by `CaptureAsync()` you just need to call:

```
byte[] result = CaptureAsync(<Your_parameters>).Result;
```

Comment: do you know how to use "GetRenderer" ? the method is not found , at least in latest xamarin forms, or maybe some extension class I am missing. any help is greatly appreciated